# Bytes-like object or Buffer type annotaion

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, type-annotation

How do I annotate a [bytes-like](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object) object or a Buffer?

There is no interface for the buffer protocol but I wish to accept all buffers in a function of mine.

I don't mind if it's only mypy-specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with [Python 3.12](https://peps.python.org/pep-0688/#collections-abc-buffer), [collections.abc.Buffer](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/collections.abc.html?highlight=buffer#collections.abc.Buffer) can be used like so:

```
from collections.abc import Buffer

def foo(buffer: Buffer):
    pass
```

Comment: Wow, it took them 8 years to come up with a type for it (since 3.5). I like Python, but type hints are like 'the interpreter doesn't care, we don't care, neither should you'.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar actually nowadays type-hints are used just about everywhere. CPython core devs tend to develop them more and more.

Answer (score 3):

Currently (as of Python 3.6) the "Buffer Protocol" is a C API thing only - you can't even talk about it in regular Python code.

cf: [Add typing.py class describing a PEP 3118 buffer object](https://bugs.python.org/issue27501)

I would use `Any` for now.

Comment: the bug can easily found by searching for "typing buffer" on bugs.python.org

Comment: I would use Union of the expected types, e.g. Union[bytes, bytearray]

Comment: @proski incorrect as plenty of others implement it. It is a semi-good workaround though.